# App registration with client secret works on dev box but not production

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an app with a development box and a production box.  On the development box, I can successfully set up an App registration with a client secret to make Azure calls using the Azure SDK, i.e. @azure/identity.

But when I use the same key on the production box (same code and everything), I receive this exception in NodeJS:

> Error in running "AZURE Inventory": Error: Error: "AuthenticationRequiredError: network_error: Network request failed at MsalClientSecret.handleError (.../node_modules/@azure/identity/dist/index.js:471:16) at MsalClientSecret.doGetToken (.../node_modules/@azure/identity/dist/index.js:3287:24) at runMicrotasks () at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) at async Object.withspan

I have looked through the Azure site to see if there is a security setting that needs to be set.  The development box is my home machine and the production box is a cloud instance.

I am puzzled as to why this is happening.  Any ideas of what to look at?  I have double-checked the subscriptionId, tenantId, clientId, and clientSecret multiple times and they match.

Thanks.

I have gone through the Azure UI multiple times to see if it was a security issue, but no pinpointed the issue yet.

Comment: You are having issue in retrieving secrets from a Node JS Azure App Service.Is this your issue?

Comment: If possible can you please share your code repro by masking the secrets?

Answer (score 0):

Found it.  Realized I had v14 of Node on production.  I upgraded to v20 and the problem went away.